# Rosetta - What score does RosettaDock use for I_sc?

Tags: bioinformatics, protein-binding, protein-interaction

I want to get a score using Rosetta for how well a protein binds to a ligand. I understand RosettaDock has a score called I_sc which will give me a number to indicate that.

I found documentation in https://www.rosettacommons.org/demos/latest/tutorials/scoring/scoring about how Rosetta scores structures, but not sure what scoring function RosettaDock uses and whether it is the *talaris2014* score.

So the question is what scoring function is used in RosettaDock for calculating I_sc.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Unless you (a) ran some absolutely ancient version of Rosetta or (b) explicitly specified a different score function, your protocol should have used the current default [ref2015](https://new.rosettacommons.org/docs/latest/rosetta_basics/scoring/Scorefunction-History). This will be the default until a few years when the next major update is released.

You can verify this by checking your log file, which should have a line like
`core.scoring.ScoreFunctionFactory:  SCOREFUNCTION: ref2015`